# Installing SharePoint Foundation 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, installation

I am trying to install Sharepoint Foundation 2013,launching the setup only causes opening  a splash.txt file

I am using windows server 2012 standard édtion, SQL Server 2014

What am I missing here ??

[image]

After choosing install sharepoint foundation I got this,no option to choose wether standalone or complete installation!!
Any suggestion Plz
[image]

Comment: Try http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5ace423f-e72a-4680-8298-092ccb1bdf43/sharepoint-2013-splashhta-not-loading?forum=sharepointadmin

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped me but there is no tab for choosing installation type !

Comment: At what step you are facing issue?

Comment: after choosing install sharepoint foundation i click accept then i have to choose a File location the server type is missing

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing the same behavior (I hardly ever install Foundation), found this link (http://sharepoint-tutorial.net/post/2012/07/18/install-sharepoint-2013-domain-controller.aspx) which indicates the tab is missing because installing SPF on a DC isn't supported:

"*Are you missing the server type selection screen? Then you're probably trying to install SharePoint 2013 on a Domain Controller where you don't have this screen available.*"

Are you attempting to install on a DC?

Brian